# Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null with Netflix

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am working on a program that connects Netflix with Discord using rich presence though I am running in a issue when I want to use the following code

```js
 if (type === 'watch' && document.querySelector('.ellipsize-text')) {
        let name = document.querySelector('.ellipsize-text')
       //let id = document.getElementById('VideoContainer').getAttribute('data-videoid');
        let span = document.querySelector('.ellipsize-text').querySelectorAll('span')
        let { duration, currentTime, paused } = document.querySelector('.VideoContainer').getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
        let title = span[1] ? span[1].innerHTML : undefined
        let episode = span[0] ? span[0].innerHTML : undefined
        console.log(document.getElementById('data-videoid').getAttribute);
        console.log("test")
        let interactive = false
        // TODO: Better interactive video check. Severe problems are caused in the solutions currently found

        name = name.querySelector('h4') ? name.querySelector('h4').innerText : name.innerText
        return { name, title, episode, duration, currentTime, paused, interactive, avatar, userName, button: [{ label: "Watch", url: "https://netflix.com/watch/"}]} //+ id}]}
    }
```

The error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1b62.png)

If you could help me out with this it would be much appreciated

Comment: You'll likely want to provide the HTML as well, as the error seems to indicate there's no element on your page with the id `data-videoid`.

Comment: `document.getElementById('data-videoid')` looks for an element with `id="data-videoid"`. I suspect what you really want is an element with `data-videoid="something"`

Comment: And `getAttribute` is a function, why are you logging that? Surely you want to call the function and log what it returns.

Comment: You commented out `//let id = document.getElementById('VideoContainer').getAttribute('data-videoid');` but there's no such Element. See the Image with error you posted - it has a class, not an ID.

Comment: Also, don't *just* use `let` as an overall replacement for `var`. Learn about the difference between `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you want is:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('[data-videoid]').dataset.videoid);
```

This will find the element that has the attribute `data-videoid="something"` and then log `something`.